# SVG - tooltip background disappearing when I use setAttribute

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, tooltip

I have the following SVG code that's supposed to display a UML diagram with tooltips and dynamically resize the viewbox if it's too small. However, when I added that last bit to resize the viewbox, it seemed to break the tooltip, so the background doesn't appear. As soon as I take out all the code with svgID, the background is there, but the text is cut off.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg id = "diagram" onload="init(evt)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="453px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:500px;height:453px;background:#FFFFFF;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 500 453" width="500px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="fbv2q8ssf24ue" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/></filter></defs>
<style>
    .tooltip{
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      fill:black;
    }
    .tooltip_bg{
      fill: yellow;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[
    function init(evt){
      if ( window.svgDocument == null ){
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
      }
      tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');
      tooltip_bg = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_bg');
    }
    function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext){
      var el = evt.target;
      var bbox = el.getBBox();
      svgID = document.getElementById("diagram"); 
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +11);
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+27);
      tooltip.firstChild.data = mouseovertext;
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
      length = tooltip.getComputedTextLength();
      if(length + bbox.x > svgID.getAattribute("width")) {
        svgID.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 1000 1000"); 
        svgID.setAttribute("width", "1000px");
        svgID.setAttribute("height", "1000px");
      }
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"width",length+8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+11);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visibile");
    }
    function HideTooltip(evt){
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
    }
  ]]>
  </script><g><rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="224.5" y="118.3125"/><rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="424.5" y="292.0703"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="90" x2="90" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="229" x2="229" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="429" x2="429" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="138" x="19" y="5"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="124" x="26" y="26.5332">webAPICreateMode</text><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="138" x="19" y="408.125"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="124" x="26" y="429.6582">webAPICreateMode</text><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="171" y="5"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="178" y="26.5332">Web API Step 1</text><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="171" y="408.125"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="178" y="429.6582">Web API Step 1</text><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="371" y="5"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="378" y="26.5332">Web API Step 2</text><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="371" y="408.125"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="378" y="429.6582">Web API Step 2</text><rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="224.5" y="118.3125"/><rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="424.5" y="292.0703"/><rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="493" x="0" y="72.7852"/><line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="493" y1="72.7852" y2="72.7852"/><line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="493" y1="75.7852" y2="75.7852"/><rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="207" x="143" y="61.6094"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="193" x="149" y="79.1045">step 1: Account.Account Credit</text><polygon fill="#A80036" points="212.5,114.3125,222.5,118.3125,212.5,122.3125,216.5,118.3125" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="90" x2="218.5" y1="118.3125" y2="118.3125"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="97" y="113.4561">1</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="59" x="108" y="113.4561">Divyaabca</text><rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="5" y="131.3125"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="9" y="148.8076"><a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'static = data')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data 1</a></text><polygon fill="#A80036" points="101,179.0156,91,183.0156,101,187.0156,97,183.0156" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="95" x2="228.5" y1="183.0156" y2="183.0156"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="107" y="178.1592">2</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="118" y="178.1592">[200]</text><rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="39" y="196.0156"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="43" y="213.5107"><a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, '
otherVar ← {{PATH2}};
saveV ← {{PATH}};')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a></text><rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="493" x="0" y="246.543"/><line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="493" y1="246.543" y2="246.543"/><line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="493" y1="249.543" y2="249.543"/><rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="296" x="98.5" y="235.3672"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="282" x="104.5" y="252.8623">step 2: Abstraction.loan_bundles_abstraction</text><polygon fill="#A80036" points="412.5,288.0703,422.5,292.0703,412.5,296.0703,416.5,292.0703" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="229.5" x2="418.5" y1="292.0703" y2="292.0703"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="236.5" y="287.2139">3</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="165" x="247.5" y="287.2139">create_loan_sanitywatercost</text><rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="144" y="305.0703"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="148" y="322.5654"><a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'some = data')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data 2</a></text><polygon fill="#A80036" points="240.5,352.7734,230.5,356.7734,240.5,360.7734,236.5,356.7734" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="234.5" x2="428.5" y1="356.7734" y2="356.7734"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="246.5" y="351.917">4</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="257.5" y="351.917">[204]</text><rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#fbv2q8ssf24ue)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="179" y="369.7734"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="183" y="387.2686"><a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, '
saveJson ← {{JSON PATH}}; words to test ')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 2</a></text><!--MD5=[4b5894ef0cb12409737c5a27bab074bf]
@startuml 
autonumber 
==step 1: Account.Account Credit== 
"webAPICreateMode"->"Web API Step 1": Divyaabca  
rnote left "webAPICreateMode"
static data 1
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 1"
"webAPICreateMode" <- - "Web API Step 1": [200] 
rnote over "webAPICreateMode"
validation data 1
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 1"
==step 2: Abstraction.loan_bundles_abstraction== 
"Web API Step 1"->"Web API Step 2": create_loan_sanitywatercost 
rnote left "Web API Step 1"
static data 2
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 2"
"Web API Step 1" <- - "Web API Step 2": [204] 
rnote over "Web API Step 1"
validation data 2
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 2"
@enduml

PlantUML version 1.2021.8(Sat Jun 26 01:20:59 PDT 2021)
(GPL source distribution)
Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Default Encoding: UTF-8
Language: en
Country: US
--></g>  <rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" ry="2" width="55" height="21" visibility="hidden"/>
  <text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden">Tooltip</text></svg>
```

Comment: you'd need to convert the right hand side of length + bbox.x > svgID.getAattribute("width") to a float for this to work.  Running the code shows this and other errors in the console.

Comment: It's a typo: svgID.getAattribute instead of `svgID.getAttribute`